# Thymeleaf & SpringBoot link Hfef adding unicode to the URL when link is clicked

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am not sure why this is happening, as I have an older project where links written this way work perfectly, but I upgraded my new project to SpringBoot 2 and Thymeleaf 3 and I keep getting this URL when I click on a link from my home page while other html pages the same link set up works correctly. This is being ran from Intellij and is not yet set up as a production application.

The link takes me to http://localhost:80/@%7B/edit/%7Bexpiring.broker.id%7D%7D  instead of http://localhost:80/edit/{broker.id}

Can anyone advise why this is happening? As I am not getting any errors since it is accurately going to a URL, its just processing the URL wrong.

Here is my HTML

```html
<table class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-classes="table-no-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th>Broker</th>
        <th>Documents</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:each="expiring:${aboutToExpire}">
            <td><a href="@{/edit/${expiring.broker.id}}"><span th:text="${expiring.broker.accountName}"></span></a></td>
            <td><span th:text="${expiring.type}"></span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my controller function:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}")
public String editBroker(Model model,@PathVariable("id") Long id, Broker broker){
    Broker existing = brokerRepository.findById(id).get();
    model.addAttribute("broker",existing);
    return "brokerProfile";
}
```

Some of my dependencies:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: In your code, you are using `href` instead of `th:href`.

Comment: Ah!! Thank you! An oversight. It fixed half, but is now having issues converting value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long' for the id portion of the URL

Comment: Figured it all out, thanks again @Metroids